# How to convert https URL image into base64 string using javascript?

Tags: javascript, image, https, base64

[Check the code in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Dayanidhicse/mbLz7gax/) This code shows error.

```
var img = document.querySelector("img");
var img1 = new Image();
             img1.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
             img1.onload = function() {
             var canvas = document.createElement('CANVAS');
             var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
             var dataURL;
             canvas.height = this.height;
             canvas.width = this.width;
             document.body.appendChild(canvas);
             ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
             dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
             console.log(dataURL);
             };

    img1.src = "https://bithin.files.wordpress.com/2012/02/https.jpg";
```

Error :

Image from origin 'https://bithin.files.wordpress.com' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: strange you get through the onload event, but if your server is not configured to send the proper cross-origin header, the error message is normal. There are already **a lot** of duplicates of this question. Please use the search input at top of the page (type in `[canvas] cross origin`or similar) PS : the only reason I can see how you could get through the onload, even when you set the `crossOrigin` is that you are using a browser that don't support this parameter.

Comment: but still i am getting answer for what i asked for dude its not accepting for https images but works fine for http images